# Best python XMPP / Jabber server library?

Tags: python, xmpp

I'm looking for a good and suitable XMPP server library!
What are your experiences with Python Jabber / XMPP server libraries? What do you recommend?

Comment: As you see, I got new answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Big fan of prosody, very easy to set up.  http://www.prosody.im

Comment: Hey @Mooseknuckles, Prosody is not python lib! I looking for XMPP server python library.